# Link to static files from Jade template rendered from a sub route

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a very basic problem with Node.js/Express/Jade that's surprisingly hard to describe. In my node.js application I use the Express framework for routing of HTTP requests. I also use Jade templates as views, who themselves link to files (css, js etc.) inside a directory that I have declared as static through the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` command.

When I route requests to resources like `/about` or `/contact` everything works as expected. But I found that as soon as my resources have multiple 'levels' like so `/about/me` the same jade view would still render, but it ends up in the browser without CSS styling!

So my assumption is that the virtual directories represented by the resource levels screw up where jade thinks it must look for relative paths (in this case, where to find the `public` directory containing the static files).

I can't just prefix the paths inside the jade template since I have to use the same template for different resource types, so I need a solution that works for arbitrary resource levels.

Is there such a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing that your Jade template has something that looks like the following:

```
doctype html
  head
    link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/style.css")
    ...
```

The `href` for the stylesheet is a relative path, meaning your browser will look for the CSS file relative to the page it is currently on.  For example:

- `http://example.com/about` →  `http://example.com/css/style.css`
- `http://example.com/about/company` →  `http://example.com/about/css/style.css`

You can change the `href` to an absolute path so the CSS file location will always be constant no matter what sub-directory you are in:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="/css/style.css")
```

The key change here is the forward slash at the beginning of the `href`, turning the relative path into an absolute one.