# Express app.get() creates new virtual directory - I don't want that

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I just changed my routing from query-strings to a kind of restful API.

Before:

```
http://www.server.de/?item=1234
```

After:

```
http://www.server.de/item/1234
```

I route these requests with Express as follows:

```
app.get('/item/:itemID', function(req, res){
    var itemID = req.param('itemID');
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/application.html');
});
```

Every file, that `application.html` wants load (like styles, images, javascripts ...) is saved in a subdirectory `assets/...` After the routing-change, they are being searched in the "virtual" directory `item/assets/...` which of course returns `404` (until I change the paths in the `.hmtl`-file).

How can I route such URLs without changing the whole context of paths?

**Edit:**

Watch Tim Coopers comment. Redefining the paths in the `.html`-file as absolute did the trick.

Comment: Did you change anything else? Cause just changing the urls shouldn't have changed the way your static resources are served.

Comment: No, I changed nothing else. Static resources are served like before with `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: ah, just edited my question, you might have been missunderstanding an information. `app.get('/item/...')` leads to loading static content from `item/...`

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23447587/142162