# using parameters in url causing included files to be downloaded from same url

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I want to get parameters from url and display content based on the parameters.

I am using express 4 here is my code

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/showcontent/:book/:page',
  function(req, res) {
    console.log("app.get parameters");

    res.render('bookPage', { book: req.params.book,page: req.params.page });
  }
);
```

in my public folder there are css and js files. when i use url with parameters like

```
mydomain.com/showcontent/book/page123
```

it tries to get css and js files from

```
mydomain.com/showcontent/book/page123/css/style.css
mydomain.com/showcontent/book/page123/js/script.js
```

while it should get the files from public folder from url

```
mydomain.com/css/style.css
mydomain.com/js/script.js
```

everything works fine if I use url format like this

```
/showcontent?book=1234&page=12345
```

but i dont want to use this format, I think some thing is missing in my code please someone help me solve to get parameters from url using forward slash format and still get css and js files from public directory

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23447587/142162) (summary: use absolute paths for your CSS and JavaScript files).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link to static files from Jade template rendered from a sub route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447449/link-to-static-files-from-jade-template-rendered-from-a-sub-route)